# wkhtmltopdf and pdfkit returning a blank pdf from url

Tags: javascript, python, pdf, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit

I'm trying to create a pdf for easy reference of jobs on google careers however when I try to create a PDF using wkhtmltopdf I'm getting a blank page.

I believe this has something to do with the html of the page itself? When I try to inspect the page source the html code is very short. There's also a few javascript links.

The URL I'm trying is [this one](https://careers.google.com/jobs/results/125555613246595782-partner-engineer-google-cloud/)

And here's the code I'm using:

```
pdfkit.from_url("https://careers.google.com/jobs/results/125555613246595782-partner-engineer-google-cloud/", 'test.pdf',
           options={'--javascript-delay': 5000})
```

Using wkhtmltopdf like this also returns a blank pdf:

```
wkhtmltopdf https://careers.google.com/jobs/results/125555613246595782-partner-engineer-google-cloud/ test.pdf
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google used client-side rendering for this page.
This is an old link, but maybe it will be useful to you
https://github.com/devongovett/node-wkhtmltopdf/issues/70

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: @IVRafa can you elaborate. I am also unable to render chards when converting html to pdf